# Java Class Exception

Tags: java, exception

I have Some  class exception to create

```
class FirstException extends Exception
class IllegalValue extends FirstException
class IllegalIntValue extends FirstException
```

I want to use this exception also in sub packeges. 
Their is a way to creat One class file with this classes and use them?
Like nested classes..

Or the only way is to create this in 3 files of public classes?

Thanks

Comment: I think you first need a beginner's tutorial on classes, packaging, inheritance, etc. in Java

Comment: Either I didn't understand what you are asking or you should read some more about what a `package` is and the `import` keyword.

Comment: make those classes public

Comment: Are you looking at creating an interface, which all your sub exception classes can implement need more information before someone can give you feedback on this.

Comment: His question is about class visibility in the project from what I understood. So making them `public` is the way to go.

Comment: You can create all the classes in one file. But in one file there can be only one public class. you can create all the classes with default level of scope(Without mentioning any specifier like public/private). so all the classes can be used within the package.

Comment: This is what I ask. Their is a way to make this classes like pulic or protected in one file. cuase is seemes not good to make 3 or 4 files with one line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to make them separate classes in three different source code files.

It is possible to have more than one class in a single source code file by using inner classes. However, I would advise against it in this case, because it would break best practice. And the compiler will still create separate `.class` files for the inner classes.

Yes, you get a lot of files. That is the way java is designed.
You don't have to like it, but you have to accept it (or switch to another language).

When it comes to using them from another package you can easily do that. Just declare the classes `public`.

```
public class FirstException extends Exception
public class IllegalValue extends FirstException
public class IllegalIntValue extends FirstException
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to declare all exception classes public and place all of them in their own files. Whether you want to put them in separate packages or not depends on what part of the code they are thrown from.

If you understand what I mean! :)

**EDIT:**

I would follow this dir package structure :

```
com.example.exception
|
|--FirstException.java
|
|--IllegalValue.java
|
|--IllegalIntValue.java
```

Each of these files containing corresponding public classes.

Comment: So I think I put them in one packege like Exception packege.. and make them all public.. this is what you mean?